# Select values when it has more than 2 different values in other column in a given period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying this for days but I still can't find out how to make this happen and hopping for some ideas.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
+------+------------------+--------+
|NAME  |WHEN              |LOCATION|
+------+------------------+--------+
|TOM   |17/05/20 00:00:00 |ABC     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |17/05/20 00:00:00 |ABC     |  
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |17/05/20 00:00:00 |XYZ     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |18/05/20 00:00:00 |TRD     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|SAM   |19/05/20 00:00:00 |ABC     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|TOM   |18/05/20 00:00:00 |ABC     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|TOM   |21/05/20 00:00:00 |ABC     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|SAM   |23/05/20 00:00:00 |XYZ     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |20/05/20 00:00:00 |XYZ     |
+------+------------------+--------+
```

I want to select any 'NAME' that has been to more than 2 'LOCATION' in 1 week(or any given period). From the table since TOM has only been to 1 location he shouldn't be picked up and the output should be something like this:

```
+------+------------------+--------+
|NAME  |WHEN              |LOCATION|
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |17/05/20 00:00:00 |ABC     |  
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |17/05/20 00:00:00 |XYZ     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |18/05/20 00:00:00 |TRD     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|SAM   |19/05/20 00:00:00 |ABC     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|SAM   |23/05/20 00:00:00 |XYZ     |
+------+------------------+--------+
|BOB   |20/05/20 00:00:00 |XYZ     |
+------+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: @zealous The datatype is 'DATE', I have simplified the date in this example...sorry if caused any confusion.

Comment: @zealous Thanks, a week to me will be "every 7 days". My plan is that I will run this on every Monday and query the past 7 days result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with `count`. here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=208b643eb73126521fd05567a9ec83b6).

```
with cte as
( select
    name, when, location,
    count(distinct location) over (partition by name) as ttl
  from myTable
)

select 
  name, location, when
from cte
where ttl > 1
```

Output:

```
|NAME | LOCATION | WHEN |
*-----------------------*
| BOB   ABC       17/05 | 
| BOB   TRD       18/05 | 
| BOB   XYZ       20/05 | 
| BOB   XYZ       17/05 | 
| SAM   ABC       19/05 | 
| SAM   XYZ       23/05 | 
*-----------------------*
```

Comment: Was taking some time to run it, it didn't work as the value like 'TOM' still showing in the output

Comment: @Phantom in the demo it is not showing `TOM`. then how you are getting it?

Comment: I am going to figure this out - Maybe I should consider that 'TOM' would also go to 'ABC' more than once in 1 day which I forgot to mention in here. But you gave me an idea of where should I be heading to. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: seems one more condition, which's restriction for one week period backwards starting from upcoming Monday, is missing.

Comment: @zealous Want to put an update here. It's working, the issue was due to my query also involves jointing multiple tables and one of column was linked incorrectly with the other one. Got that corrected and it gives me the expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code, It will help you

```
declare @from_date smalldatetime = '2020-05-17'
        ,@to_date smalldatetime ='2020-05-23' 
declare @tab as table(name varchar(50),whn smalldatetime,location varchar(50))

insert into @tab values('TOM','2020-05-17','ABC')
,('BOB','2020-05-17','ABC')
,('BOB','2020-05-17','XYZ')
,('BOB','2020-05-18','TRD')
,('SAM','2020-05-19','ABC')
,('TOM','2020-05-18','ABC')
,('TOM','2020-05-21','ABC')
,('SAM','2020-05-23','XYZ')
,('BOB','2020-05-20','XYZ')

select a.* from @tab  a
inner join
(
select name,count(distinct c.location) cnt from tab c where whn between @from_date and @to_date
group by c.name having count(distinct c.location)>1
) b
on a.name=b.name
```

**Output**

```
name    whn location
BOB 2020-05-17 00:00:00 ABC
BOB 2020-05-17 00:00:00 XYZ
BOB 2020-05-18 00:00:00 TRD
BOB 2020-05-20 00:00:00 XYZ
SAM 2020-05-23 00:00:00 XYZ
SAM 2020-05-19 00:00:00 ABC
```

Comment: have you noticed that the DBMS is tagged `oracle`?

Comment: I didn't. Thanks. I wrote a query for SQL server.